# I need a name for a space survival game

Tags: game-design

I am making a game similar to [planetbase](http://store.steampowered.com/app/403190/). It will have mining systems, and you trade resources with traders that come periodically. You can sell your extra minerals, and buy other things with the money.

What is different about this game than [planetbase](http://store.steampowered.com/app/403190/) is that there is also a space station orbiting the planet, and you have a space elevator to go between them. Some minerals you can only find in asteroids orbiting and some only on the planet.

***Question:*** **What is a name idea for this game?**

Comment: We do not do "suggest a name" questions, here. A good rule of thumb is to ask yourself if there would be an *absolute* answer to your question. Questions like "what should I name my game" are just going to attract opinion-based answers, which is not what were generally about, at Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wanted to give you a serious answer, so here it goes. First off, this is an opinion based question. We can only give you our opinion on what a good name will be, and thus, this question is off topic for this site. Also, let me paraphrase your mentality right now with a single sentence: "A thousand ideas, zero lines of code."

Make your game. Use a codename at the beginning, like "Project Black". Most game companies do this, even for major games, but this is also to keep the project somewhat secret. My point is, you're wasting time and procrastinating. Make your game, then name it. It should also be noted that even games like Minecraft were first created without a name; the earliest builds of it were just called "RubyDung". You need to avoid wasting time on trivial things like this until far later into your project. Like right now, and I'm not trying to brag or anything, but I am currently sitting on (Runs code metrics for entire solution) 44,324 lines of code for my game. That's with a working inventory system, rendering, player attributes, loot systems, entity systems, weather systems, etc, and all hosted within a custom game engine framework that I created from the ground up.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'm new here, i think i'll remove the question later than. Well, I have started the game, but i'm nowhere near done. I'll take your advice and make the game first Thanks again!

Comment: i see your edit, my game has 4681 lines of code (also using Visual Studio Code Metrics). I guess I have a long ways to go then.

Comment: @NoahHeber there is no magical number of lines after which a piece of software is complete. you can have more or less than another project,as long as the resulting game meets the goals you set for it. :)